# Subclassing Probe doesn't work

Tags: qbs

I am trying to subclass Probe to clone custom repositories from the net before starting the build.

GitProbe:

```
import qbs
import qbs.File
import qbs.Process

Probe {
    property string gitUrl
    property string wd
    property string name
    property string dir: wd + "/" + name
    configure: {
        try {
            if(File.directoryEntries(dir, File.AllEntries).length > 0){
                File.remove(dir)
            }
            var gitProcess = Process()
            gitProcess.setWorkingDirectory(wd)
            gitProcess.exec("git", ["clone", gitUrl], true)
            found = true
        } catch(err) {
            console.warn("GitProbe : could not clone repository " + gitUrl)
            console.error("GitProbe : " + err)
            found = false
        }
    }
}
```

I did put the `GitProbe.qbs` in `dir/imports/` , and in my project I did `qbsSearchPath: "path-to-dir"`, but qbs tell me when parsing the file `Unexpected item type 'GitProbe'`.

Comment: The directory name needs to be "imports", not "import".

Comment: yes it is it was a typo in the question text.

Comment: Ok. Please post a complete, but minimal project somewhere so I can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ChristianKandeler : here is the link of a mini project where I get the error https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzuf-c53BXVzakdmS2ktdlh4N2M/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known limitation: The search path needs to be set already when the current file is parsed. So the workaround is to reference your file from a Project item in another file and set the search path there. You might want to vote on https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QBS-667.